# AngularJS - Clean way to have many service dependencies without calling them

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a service that ("A") needs to be loaded after ~10 other services are loaded ("B" - "L"), because those other 10 each make a call on their startup, and "A" needs those each to be called.

What I know I can do is

```
var module = angular.module('AModule',[]); 

module.service('A', ['B', 'C', 'D',...'L', function() {
     //A's functionality
    }
]);
```

However, within A I never explicitly call any of the other service's methods, and I've never seen a pattern where a service is declared with dependencies on other services, where those services aren't actually injected/used. Is there a better way to do this?

What I tried to do was have

```
var module = angular.module('AModule',[
     BThroughLModule
]);
```

Where BThroughLModule registers the B through L services. But that didn't work - declaring the module dependency didn't guarantee the services of those modules were instantiated before the A module.

Comment: @georgeawg  The other services make a call on instantiation. The A service needs them all to have made that call before it instantiates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `$watchGroup` in a controller to check when a `isLoaded` property is set to true for all your B ... L services, and only when all of them have that property set to true, then you run a function in service A to load it. Please see sample below.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope, A, B, C) {
    $scope.A = A;
    $scope.B = B;
    $scope.C = C;

    var watchGroup = [
      'B.isLoaded',
      'C.isLoaded'
    ];

    $scope.$watchGroup(watchGroup, function(watchGroup) {
      for (var i = 0; i < watchGroup.length; i++) {
        if (!watchGroup[1]) {
          return;
        }
      }
      A.loadService();
    });
  })
  .factory('A', function($timeout) {
    var service = {
      isLoaded: false,
      loadService: loadService
    };

    function loadService() {
      $timeout(function() { //simulate api call
        service.isLoaded = true;
      }, 1000)
    }

    return service;
  })
  .factory('B', function($timeout) {
    var service = {
      isLoaded: false
    };

    $timeout(function() { //simulate api call
      service.isLoaded = true;
    }, 3000)


    return service;
  })
  .factory('C', function($timeout) {
    var service = {
      isLoaded: false
    };

    $timeout(function() { //simulate api call
      service.isLoaded = true;
    }, 5000)

    return service;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
  <div>Service A is loaded (when B and C are loaded): {{A.isLoaded}}</div>
  <div>Service B is loaded: {{B.isLoaded}}</div>
  <div>Service C is loaded: {{C.isLoaded}}</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the individual service's themselves making a call on their instantiation, you can do something as following.

Expose an init method on all the services. Then, create a service module and inject all the services in module.run() block and call all service init methods. This way it is much cleaner and you do not to keep track of whether the services were loaded or not. You can then add service module as dependency to Main module.

```
angular.module('Services.Init', [])
       .run(['A','B','C', 'D', function(A, B, C, D){
            A.init();
            B.init();
            C.init();
            D.init();
        });

angular.module('Main', ['Services.Init']);
```